# Apply Right-To-Left to a tooltip on a WinForms StatusStrip

Tags: winforms, tooltip, statusstrip

In my **WinForms** application, I'm currently populating a **StatusStrip** with multiple **ToolStripStatusLabel** controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.aspx

The only tooltip property that exists is **ToolTipText**. I have no reference to a **ToolTip** object.

How can I apply **Right-To-Left** layout on this tooltip?

Thanks for any help!